# How to find the namespace to import from for Angular 2?

Tags: angular

All:

I am pretty new to ES6/TYPESCRIPT/Angular2, when I went thru the tutorial of Angular2 official site, the first thing confuses me is:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
```

My question is:

**What is that "angular2/core"? is that a module directory? or just a namespace string? When I use a component or module, how/where do I find this part?**

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might wanna read this part [this](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/architecture.html#!#module) from doc first

> `import {AppComponent} from './app.component';`
>   The import statement tells the system it can get an AppComponent from
>   a module named app.component located in a neighboring file. The module
>   name (AKA module id) is often the same as the filename without its
>   extension.

and [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

> module-name: The name of the module to import. This is a file name.

It should mean a file called core.js, which is [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-build.8516473.js/core.js).

And since the module name is the same with filename, so you can see it is from a module called core.

Where to find this ?

for example, if you want to use **http** service.

look it up in the document api

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/

http is under **angular2/http** section

I think that is a good clue that you should import this from angular2/http

Comment: Thanks, I will follow this to dive into.